# Oracle throwing "invalid identifier" on COUNT() alias within GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to return the following three columns: Song ID, Song name, Times Played.
This represents a list of requested and played songs.

Assumptions:

1. Table SONG has SONG_ID and SONG_NAME, one row for each song
2. Table SONG_REQUEST only has SONG_ID for each time the song is requested
3. Table PLAY has SONG_ID for each time the song is played

This is my query:

```
SELECT r.SONG_ID, s.SONG_NAME, COUNT(p.SONG_ID) AS TimesPlayed
FROM PLAY p
INNER JOIN SONG s ON p.SONG_ID = s.SONG_ID
LEFT JOIN SONG_REQUEST r ON p.SONG_ID = r.SONG_ID
GROUP BY p.SONG_ID, s.SONG_NAME, TimesPlayed
```

The error thrown is:

```
ORA-00904: "TIMESPLAYED": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 33
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to aggregate on your aggregate function!

Comment: Besides which, Oracle (unlike some other DBMSes) doesn't allow you to reference aliases defined at the same "level" in the group by clause.

Comment: If I remove the alias, I get "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT r.SONG_ID, s.SONG_NAME, COUNT(p.SONG_ID) AS TimesPlayed
FROM PLAY p
INNER JOIN SONG s ON p.SONG_ID = s.SONG_ID
LEFT JOIN SONG_REQUEST r ON p.SONG_ID = r.SONG_ID
GROUP BY r.SONG_ID, s.SONG_NAME;
```

Note that in the `group by` clause I've reference the *exact same* columns as in the `select` clause (changed alias `p` to `r`).

Answer (score 3):

Oracle doesn't allow to use aliases from the `SELECT` clasuse in the `GROUP BY` clause (you'd need to write `COUNT(p.SONG_ID)` again) but it doesn't make much sense to group by `TimesPlayed` anyway. You probably want to remove it entirely.

Also, you select these columns:

```
r.SONG_ID, s.SONG_NAME
```

... but attempt to group by

```
p.SONG_ID, s.SONG_NAME
```

Is it a typo?

Comment: Hi Álvaro, it wasn't a typo, but now I see that it was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a column alias in the group by or order clauses.

In any case, as Colin points out, you'd actually group by the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: Thanks David, noted for the future.